# Nagios/Icinga - find host by custom variable with cmd/status.cgi

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga

I'm looking for solution how to get a hostname from Nagios/Icinga by searching it by custom variable with cmd/status.cgi.

I have a custom variable with unique specific IDs on every host. I have to get the hostname by searching on ID. There is a documentation for CGI commands but I could not find the needed functionality: https://icinga.com/docs/icinga1/latest/en/cgiparams.html

UPD: I am using python for CGI requests. Maybe there is also a library to do that.

Does anyone know, if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

For Nagios at least, this is possible.  You can call the host details on the objectjson.cgi for a hostgroup and in your result.json(), you would have the custom_variables for each of the hosts. With that, you can map an ID to the hostname.

make your request to https://<your_url>/nagios/cgi-bin/objectjson.cgi?query=hostlist&details=true&hostgroup=<your_hostgroup>

```
{...
   "data": {
       "hostlist": {
          "<host1>": {
              ....
              "custom_variables": {
                  <custom host variables dict>
              },
          "<host2>": {
              ....
          }
       }
    }
}
```

untested! using python's requests module:

```
hostlist = result.json().get('data').get('hostlist')

id_map = {hostlist.get(host).get('custom_variables').get('your_id_key'):host for host in hostlist.keys()}
```